# Why can't I export a netcdf file from a xarray in Python (Mac OS)?

Tags: python, scheduler, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to work with netcdf files on my macbook pro (macOS Mojave 10.14.6). For some reason, I can't export any of the xarray datasets I made to net cdf files. Basically, I am trying to create monthly netcdf files  inside a for loop which I would like to export in order for me to use the results of each iteration later in my script. I imported xarray and netCDF4. Down below is some of my code which is in my for loop (which iterates over a list of months).

```
# Xarray
tas_xr = xr.DataArray(bilt_month, dims = ['years'], coords = {'years':years})
tas_xr.attrs['units'] = 'degrees Celsius'
tas_xr.attrs['month'] = month

tas_g_xr = xr.DataArray(global_month, dims = ['years'], coords = {'years':years})
tas_g_xr.attrs['units'] = 'degrees Celsius'
tas_g_xr.attrs['month'] = month

# Dataset
ds = tas_xr.to_dataset(name = 'tas_Bilt')
ds['tas_global'] = tas_g_xr

# Exporting
file_out = 'obs_data_'+month+'.nc'
ds.to_netcdf(data + file_out, 'w')
```

Where data is a string variable which contains the location of where I want the netcdf files to be stored. The program runs fine until the last line, where I get the following error:

*AttributeError: module 'dask.base' has no attribute 'get_scheduler'*

Anyone familiar with this error? I have downloaded and installed, xcode, homebrew, macports and xquartz because I heard that netcdf libraries are not necessary compatible with mac OS, and while it seems my terminal is now capable of running the ncview function (which before installing xquartz it wasn't), my Python script still gives me errors when trying to export xarrays to netcdf files.

(Hoping my question is a correct one, as I am new to using stackoverflow and Python)

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your dask - it appears that your xarray is ahead; but it would be good to give your versions in the question. The function `get_scheduler` is certainly there now.

Comment: Im sorry for not replying until now, but that worked. Thanks a bunch from a python rookie!